# Internal_failure while getting refreshtoken using code?

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-oauth, access-token, google-authentication

We are getting **internal_failure** error message while exchanging code to get refresh token. This error doesn't occur all the time for all the accounts. This happens only while authenticating with a few Google accounts and that too like 5 to 6 failures for every 10 authentication requests no matter what the client_id is. We have a test account and is reproducible too frequently in this account as well.

`{
  "error" : "internal_failure"
}`

Answer (score 2):

How often are you making these requests? You are probably running into the per account quota limits.
In real life, any account would not be doing a lot of code to refresh token conversion. The expectation is that you do that just once per application.
So, if you have test/monitoring accounts, they will run into these issues. The best is for you to monitor and test only your site/code.

Answer (score 0):

`internal_failure` is an authentication server outage. which can be tracked on

[Cloud Status](https://status.cloud.google.com/) or apparently also [APP Status](https://www.google.com/appsstatus#hl=en&v=status) although I am not seeing it there it may only be GSuite issues are there.

There is nothing that you can do but wait for the server to return.